# How to make sure that one ID does not overlap (pine script)

Tags: api

When there are five order ids, G1, G2, G3, G4, and G5, is there a way not to overlap?

```
if inDateRange
for i = 1 to 10 by 1
    i_s = str.tostring(i)
    strategy.entry('G' + i_s, strategy.long, limit=support(i))

for i = 1 to 10 by 1
i_s = str.tostring(i)
strategy.exit(id='G' + i_s, from_entry='G' + i_s, limit=target(i))
```

If you don't pyramid, five orders won't enter.

If you give a pyramid, one order will be repeated.

Comment: What is this? In Python? The indentation seems incorrect for both the 'if' statement and the second 'for' loop (whether required by the language or not). Can you add some more tags? What do you mean by "If you don't pyramid, five orders won't enter."? Can you elaborate?

Comment: What is "pine script"? *"Pine Script ... scripting language called Pine Script . It allows users to create custom indicators and run them on our servers. ... Pine Script is the name of the programming language utilized by TradingView 's proprietary HTML5 charting software"*